# What does "ne s’y serait pas pris autrement" mean?

Tags: sens

For practice, I read news articles in French. I try to understand all of the fine points, and most of the time, I succeed. Now I've stumbled upon one with one phrase that I really don't understand. I have copy-pasted the whole article for context:

> Aurait-il voulu des ennuis avec la justice que Dimitri, 28 ans, **ne s’y serait pas pris autrement**. Le 25 mars dernier, dans les rues de Montdidier, un policier en civil remarque la conduite dangereuse de ce militaire en permission, au volant de sa Citroën Xsara.
>
> Le policier appelle les gendarmes, le peloton de surveillance intervient alors que Dimitri a garé sa voiture. Pour se tenir tranquille ? Non. Le jeune homme chevauche maintenant une Suzuki Bandit, au guidon de laquelle il nargue les militaires, passe sous leur nez, accélère violemment, roule sur une roue. Il est finalement interpellé et renvoyé devant le tribunal pour le délit de mise en danger d’autrui (les piétons) et un total de huit contraventions.
>
> A l’audience de mardi 27, l’artilleur était tout penaud. Il a expliqué se trouver le 25 mars sous le coup de l’alcool et des médicaments, lui qui peine à se remettre d’une déception sentimentale.
>
> Le tribunal l’a condamné à six mois de prison avec sursis, et un total de 850 euros d’amende.
>
> Source: http://www.courrier-picard.fr/region/montdidier-il-nargue-les-gendarmes-sur-sa-moto-ia0b0n380108

Comment: je pense que tu as raté un "il" quelque part:  "ne s’y serait-il pas pris autrement." ça doit être du conditionnel future passé .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This expression means that the action which is following (conduire dangereusement) is the surest way to reach the goal announced in the first half of the first phrase (avoir des ennuis avec la justice). It could be translated to something like: "Had he been looking for trouble, he couldn't have found a better way."